# How can I install a Voice chat application Server and Client for Windows

Tags: webrtc, voip, intranet

I would like to setup a **Voip Server and Client for Windows** but when I searched on Google, there was too many results and too many softwares.

I want to setup a Voip sytem for my **Intranet**, that's why I can't use Skype. Because all the user of my computer are in different rooms I would like to be able to call the users easily by a voice chat application.

What are the best free softwares ?

Thank your for your help.

EDIT 1: I think I didn't give enough details: Thank you mrescape for your help but I don't want to create a program, I just want to download one.

EDIT 2 : I finally discovered [WebRTC](https://webrtc.org/) and decided to use this technology, it will be much easier to setup in my environment...

Comment: That's off-topic, Stack Overflow is about programming questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

About VoIP server you can use http://www.asteriskwin32.com. And about client you can use X-lite or Portgo, Linephone ...

Comment: great to hear that :)